# C segmentation fault when writing into a file

Tags: c

I was trying to calculate the average of each line in this file:

> ```
>  alpha 94 86 72 83
>  beta 83 65 98 54
>  charlie 69 70 59 43
> ```

The code is this:

> ```
>  #include "stdio.h"
>  #include "stdlib.h"
>  #include "math.h"
>  #include "string.h"
>  int main()
>  {
>     char *n,*p;
>     char line[150];
>     char line1[149];
>     int average=0,sum=0,inte=0,i=0,a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,g;
>     FILE *fp,*des;
>     char *array[5],*array2[5];
>     fp=fopen("score.txt","r");
>     des=fopen("avarage.txt","w+");
>     int num1[3]={0,0,0};
>  while (1) {
>         if (fgets(line,150, fp) == NULL)
>         break;
>         int i=0;        
>         memcpy( line1, &line[0], strlen(line)-1 );
>         array[0] = strtok(line1," ");
>         while(array[i]!=NULL)
>         {
>             array[i++] = p;
>         p=strtok(NULL," ");
>         inte=atoi(p);
>         num1[i]+=inte;
>     }
> }
> fprintf(des,"%d\n",(num1[0]+num1[1]+num1[2]+num1[3])/4);
> fclose(fp);
> fclose(des);
> return 0;
> ```
>
> }

I think this program is fine.But when I execute it, it show Segmentation fault on it. And before `fprintf(des,"%d\n",(num1[0]+num1[1]+num1[2]+num1[3])/4);` it's all fine. can some one point the problem?

Comment: "I think this program is fine" - clearly it's not if you get a seg fault! Use your debugger...

Comment: You use `strtok` on `line1` which does not contain a string

Comment: You don't check for any errors at all. `fopen()` can return `NULL` in case it failed to open the file. Check for problems. Also, there is a lot of code here, are you sure it fails when it tries to *write* to the file? Debug it properly.

Comment: Thank you, maybe it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at least you should check the pointer des and fp, if one of them is NULL, you will definitely get a SEG FAULT.

To find out exact reason, use printf() to set a checkpoint, or use debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems likely to be homework, I'm not going to say exactly what I think the problem is.  But I'll point out some facts that you don't seem to be taking into account:

1 - string functions like strtok() expect strings to be terminated by a null byte

2 - memcpy() is not a string function, and simply copies bytes from one location to another